# Using Ubuntu 12.10 and LAMP

Tags: server

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 LTS Desktop and LAMP on Dedicated HD running Win& 64bit.
When I try to Start Apache2  with sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start I get error message on dashboard "Sorry there is nothing that matches your search" this happens wit many commands in the Terminal. As best I can see LAMP installed correctly.
I need to configure it as my Test Server to run and upgrade my Joomla 1.7 Site.
I am new to Linux, Apache, PHP, My SQL and My PHP Admin. I am a Windows user but am happy and interested to learn this new to me system.
Can anyone assist a Novice Please

Answer (score 0):

The "Sorry there is nothing that matches your search" message seems to me to be from the dash search and not from a terminal.

The start command for apache2 needs to be typed in a terminal session so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to get into a terminal and execute

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```